# Cryptography - remote SQL Server + desktop app

Tags: c#

I'm developing a desktop app. that should work over Internet and communicate with remote DB. App's data have to be encrypted wile transfer.

The simplest way is to create the static key and use it while read-write the data from DB. But if I do so I would not be able to change that key. I suppose there are solutions that allow to solve this problem.

Can you tell, please, how do developers operate when they need dynamic encryption in their app's?

Thank you

Comment: are you wanting to have a seed ..? do a google search on simple encryption SHA1 using C# .NET lots of examples and approaches to encryption over the internetnet

Comment: Well, I know I can simply use a crypto function. But It would use only 1 secret. And it would not be changed in future. I want the app to be flexible.

I use SHA1 to encrypt passwords, not data

Comment: you can use that as well to encrypt data but I would still google encrypting Data and all the different ways. you could Serialize the data, then encrypt.. what is it specifically you want to do post an small snippet of example of what it is you want to encrypt..

Comment: The encrypted data will be the simple text message. The app will be used to communicate with remote employees and to set them tasks.
I can use symmetric encryption, but I avoid being not able to change the key in the future or afraid that the key would be unsafe in the App

There will be only administrator app, the client app and remote MSSQL

Comment: do the tasks contain sensitive information...?? if not then is there a reason why you would need to encrypt.. ? is this a winforms base application or a web based..? ever consider a web service that would send messages to something like a TaskQueue..?

Comment: It contains. This encryption would only be used by a couple of tables, other tables will stay unencrypted. 
This is WPF app

Comment: ok well provide an example of what the data would look like without compromising your internal data integrity if you know what I mean..

Comment: The DB table will look like ID, Message, From_User, To_User. 

ID, From_User, To_User are GUID. Message is varchar(max). I thought I would use encryption to the byte array and then .ToString() to store the sensitive text information

Comment: ok here is a good idea.. if you have a varchar() field in the data base.. why not have a method that you call that does the encryption of the data there.. then do the Insert..then when you want to validate or unencrypt the data have the unencrypt logic Method stored in a Web Method or a .DLL not sure if that would help.. I do not think that table layout of fields out side of what you are tryingto store encrypted data matters.. I will look for my code that I have used to encrypte inputs from a command wnd and see if that will help you.. let me look for this real quick

Comment: Thank you!
In general it is possible to encrypt and decrypt data by te app if my app will use the key. The problem is how to change the key in future. Yes, it is possible to read and to re-encrypt the data, but the new key will be transfered unencrypted, that's, I think, is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy this code and test it anyway you want.. WPF Console App ect..

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

public static class DataEncryption
{
   public static string Encrypt(string input, string key)
   {
      byte[] inputArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
      TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tripleDES = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
      tripleDES.Key = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
      tripleDES.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
      tripleDES.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
      ICryptoTransform cTransform = tripleDES.CreateEncryptor();
      byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(inputArray, 0, inputArray.Length);
      tripleDES.Clear();
      return Convert.ToBase64String(resultArray, 0, resultArray.Length);
   }

   public static string Decrypt(string input, string key)
   {
      byte[] inputArray = Convert.FromBase64String(input);
      TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tripleDES = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
      tripleDES.Key = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
      tripleDES.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
      tripleDES.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
      ICryptoTransform cTransform = tripleDES.CreateDecryptor();
      byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(inputArray, 0, inputArray.Length);
      tripleDES.Clear();
      return UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultArray);
   }
}
```

this should give you an idea of what I am talking about.

Comment: here is a link that you may want to look at incase you need other utilities as well http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/doc.1111/e14300/security_utils.htm I posted a link as well for a project located on CodeProject

Comment: That's what I thought it should be - the method to encrypt and to decrypt data. But each of employees, using the app would use one key. The main problem is to provide them the new keys using my app

Comment: you would have to look at Public Key vs Private Keys.. also Alex why not have an appliation that knows the Key and have some sort of authentication method put in place via AD / LDAP / SSO ect.. or Domain that way if they are a valid user then BAM! they can get their messages and or Tasks.. just an Idea

Comment: if you want to learn how to use passPhrase look at this link too http://www.obviex.com/samples/Encryption.aspx

Comment: That's a good idea! Think it is possible to use VPN to communicate within the private network

Comment: Vote up when ever you like LOL lots of great ideas here its just up to you how you would like to implement those ideas.. there is no true wrong answer just lots of good right ideas

Comment: Well VPN uses some sort of Authentication as well never had to use it.. but it has to work off the same principals of Authentication Verification .. if you are going over VPN you may not need to do encryption since in theory nobody else should be able to gain access to your network.. since that  VPN or Key thing should change every so many minutes depending on how they have that setup

Answer (score 1):

> *that should work over Internet and communicate with remote DB*

This is one of the things that happens with SSL/[TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security). The server and client set up a secure channel that eavesdroppers cannot intercept. I'd recommend reading the book [Applied Cryptography](http://www.schneier.com/book-applied.html) to learn how this, and other similar protocols work. [PGP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy) is a reasonably familiar application that you may wish to study.

> *how do developers operate when they need dynamic encryption in their apps?*

Generally, previous employers have used self-generated [public key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) certificates. Depending on the business needs, either each version of the software gets a different cert, or each user gets a different cert (this ends up as part of the license key that each user gets). If one is leaked, that individual certificate can be revoked.

Comment: "Depending on the business needs, either each version of the software gets a different cert"

It means there were many public keys and was only one private that could decrypt any of public?

Comment: @Alex, no, each version had a different private certificate, and part of the protocol included version number in the handshaking, so the server looked  up the proper public cert to decode that specific private cert.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to encrypt data for transfer only, then you should use an encrypted (i.e. SSL/TLS) connection. MS SQL Server supports this:

[Encrypting Connections to SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189067.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[How To Do Simple Encryption](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/DotNetCrypto.aspx)

Try this Code as well it also works really well .. basically what ever string you want encrypted just pass that string to the methods you may have to alter the code to work for your project feel fee to consume the code as you please.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace EncryptStringSample
{
    class MainClass
    {

        public static string EncryptString(string Message, string Passphrase)
        {
            byte[] Results;
            System.Text.UTF8Encoding UTF8 = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();

            // Step 1. We hash the passphrase using MD5
            // We use the MD5 hash generator as the result is a 128 bit byte array
            // which is a valid length for the TripleDES encoder we use below

            MD5CryptoServiceProvider HashProvider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] TDESKey = HashProvider.ComputeHash(UTF8.GetBytes(Passphrase));

            // Step 2. Create a new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider object
            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider TDESAlgorithm = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();

            // Step 3. Setup the encoder
            TDESAlgorithm.Key = TDESKey;
            TDESAlgorithm.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            TDESAlgorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            // Step 4. Convert the input string to a byte[]
            byte[] DataToEncrypt = UTF8.GetBytes(Message);

            // Step 5. Attempt to encrypt the string
            try
            {
                ICryptoTransform Encryptor = TDESAlgorithm.CreateEncryptor();
                Results = Encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(DataToEncrypt, 0, DataToEncrypt.Length);
            }
            finally
            {
                // Clear the TripleDes and Hashprovider services of any sensitive information
                TDESAlgorithm.Clear();
                HashProvider.Clear();
            }

            // Step 6. Return the encrypted string as a base64 encoded string
            return Convert.ToBase64String(Results);
        }

        public static string DecryptString(string Message, string Passphrase)
        {
            byte[] Results;
            System.Text.UTF8Encoding UTF8 = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();

            // Step 1. We hash the passphrase using MD5
            // We use the MD5 hash generator as the result is a 128 bit byte array
            // which is a valid length for the TripleDES encoder we use below

            MD5CryptoServiceProvider HashProvider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] TDESKey = HashProvider.ComputeHash(UTF8.GetBytes(Passphrase));

            // Step 2. Create a new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider object
            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider TDESAlgorithm = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();

            // Step 3. Setup the decoder
            TDESAlgorithm.Key = TDESKey;
            TDESAlgorithm.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            TDESAlgorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            // Step 4. Convert the input string to a byte[]
            byte[] DataToDecrypt = Convert.FromBase64String(Message);

            // Step 5. Attempt to decrypt the string
            try
            {
                ICryptoTransform Decryptor = TDESAlgorithm.CreateDecryptor();
                Results = Decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(DataToDecrypt, 0, DataToDecrypt.Length);
            }
            finally
            {
                // Clear the TripleDes and Hashprovider services of any sensitive information
                TDESAlgorithm.Clear();
                HashProvider.Clear();
            }

            // Step 6. Return the decrypted string in UTF8 format
            return UTF8.GetString( Results );
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // The message to encrypt.
            string Msg = "This world is round, not flat, don't believe them!";
            string Password = "secret";

            string EncryptedString = EncryptString(Msg, Password);
            string DecryptedString = DecryptString(EncryptedString, Password);

            Console.WriteLine("Message: {0}",Msg);
            Console.WriteLine("Password: {0}",Password);
            Console.WriteLine("Encrypted string: {0}",EncryptedString);
            Console.WriteLine("Decrypted string: {0}",DecryptedString);
        }
    }
}
```